# SQL - Add a new column with a default value to all tables in the DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following statement:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable '
    DECLARE @defaultId integer;
    SET @defaultId = 13;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE Name = N''?'' AND xtype = N''U'')
    BEGIN   
        IF COL_LENGTH(''[?]'',''NewColumn'') IS NULL
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE [?] ADD NewColumn integer null
            UPDATE [?]
            SET NewColumn = @defaultId
        END
    END
'
```

I'm trying to add `NewColumn` column to all the tables in my DB that don't have it and set the default value to `13`. I execute it and it says it completed successfully, but nothing has changed. What am I doing wrong here?

---

Note: I got a table called `User` hence the `"[]"`. I don't know if this adds extra complexity to it.

Comment: Aside: You may want to have a look at [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql). Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: @HABO Thanks. I've updated the tags accordingly.

Comment: Although mentioned in the accepted answer below: The table called USER is not the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't particulary like debugging `sp_MSforeachtable` code so I suggest you this method:

```
DECLARE @Name AS VARCHAR(128)

DECLARE C_Table CURSOR FOR
    SELECT sys.objects.Name
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE sys.objects.type = 'U' AND
        sys.objects.Name NOT IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT sys.objects.Name
            FROM sys.objects INNER JOIN
            sys.columns ON sys.objects.object_id = sys.columns.object_id 
            WHERE sys.objects.type = 'U' AND
                sys.columns.Name = 'NewColumn'
        )

OPEN C_Table
FETCH NEXT FROM C_Table INTO @Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    EXEC('ALTER TABLE ' + @Name + ' ADD NewColumn INTEGER NULL')
    EXEC('ALTER TABLE ' + @Name + ' ADD CONSTRAINT DF_' + @Name + '_A DEFAULT 13 FOR NewColumn')
    EXEC('UPDATE ' + @Name + ' SET NewColumn = 13')

    FETCH NEXT FROM C_Table INTO @Name

END

CLOSE C_Table
DEALLOCATE C_Table
```

This is an alternative solution using `sp_MSforeachtable` and your syntax; please note that:

- you need to [`PARSENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql) the name provided by `sp_MSforeachtable` (i.e. `[yourschema].[yourtable]`) because `sys.objects.name` contains only table name (i.e.: `yourtable`)
- you have to use 2 step because it seems that is not possible to use [`GO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037(v=sql.90).aspx) inside a `sp_MSforeachtable`
- you can't use variable in `ALTER TABLE` but you must specify a fixed `DEFAULT`

This is the code:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable '

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE Name = PARSENAME(''?'', 1) AND xtype = N''U'')
    BEGIN   
        IF COL_LENGTH(PARSENAME(''?'', 1), ''NewColumn'') IS NULL
        BEGIN
            ALTER TABLE ? ADD NewColumn INT NULL DEFAULT(13)
        END
    END

'

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable '

    DECLARE @defaultId INT
    SELECT @defaultId = 13

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE Name = PARSENAME(''?'', 1) AND xtype = N''U'')
    BEGIN   
        IF NOT COL_LENGTH(''?'', ''NewColumn'') IS NULL
        BEGIN
            UPDATE ? SET NewColumn = @defaultId
        END
    END

'
```

Comment: Had issues with this since I have a table called `User`, but I've then renamed it to something else and it works now.

Comment: @kei: This is no answer to your question. There are two  problem with your statement: 1. you need to parse the right name of the table. 2. you have to seperate the steps. It has nothing to do with a table called USER

Answer (score 1):

Most likely that `NewColumn` is not recognized. try

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable '
DECLARE @defaultId integer;
SET @defaultId = 13;
IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE Name = PARSENAME(''?'',1) AND xtype = N''U'')
BEGIN   
    IF COL_LENGTH(''?'',''NewColumn'') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE ? ADD NewColumn integer null
        EXEC(CONCAT(''UPDATE ? SET NewColumn = '', @defaultId))
    END
END'
```

Comment: @kei putting this here so you know the cause of the initial issue. `?` includes schema so first `IF` always returned false. updated my answer for future reference

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this in two steps.

The update statement is evaluated before execution and will throw an error (as there is no column at this moment)

Step 1 (alter table):

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable '

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE Name = parsename(N''?'', 1) AND xtype = N''U'')
BEGIN   
    IF COL_LENGTH(''[?]'',''NewColumn'') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE [?] ADD NewColumn integer null
    END
END
'
```

Step 2 (set value):

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable '
DECLARE @defaultId integer;
SET @defaultId = 13;

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sysobjects WHERE Name = parsename(N''?'', 1) AND xtype = N''U'')
BEGIN   
    IF COL_LENGTH(''[?]'',''NewColumn'') IS not NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [?]
        SET NewColumn = @defaultId
    END
END
'
```

You mentioned a default value. You only updated the values of the new column with a fixed value without defining a default. This might be an difference although not important for this issue.

Comment: No error message. Similar to what I was getting on my original code.

Comment: Changed and added parsename-function. MS_foreachtable returns "schema.table".